# How to put the wx.grid into a GridBagSizer, with scroll bar

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I wrote some code in Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
import wx
import wx.grid


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Manager")
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(hgap=0, vgap=0)

        overall = wx.grid.Grid(self)
        overall.CreateGrid(5,2)
        sizer.Add(overall, pos=(0,0), span=(5,2), flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Fit()

app = wx.PySimpleApp()
MainFrame().Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

It will display a 5x2 grid.
But if I changed:

```
sizer.Add(overall, pos=(0,0), span=(5,2), flag=wx.EXPAND)
```

into:

```
sizer.Add(overall, pos=(0,0), span=(4,2), flag=wx.EXPAND)
```

**Nothing will changed** :(
But I want to put a 5x2 grid into a GridBagSizer with 4x2 space, and a scroll bar.

How to do it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GridBagSizer is for actually putting multiple widgets into a grid-like shape, such as when you have a form with pairs of labels and text controls. It's not for just one widget in most cases.

You should use a BoxSizer. I find them more flexible anyway. Also wx.PySimpleApp is deprecated. Use wx.App(False) instead. Here is some code that works:

```
import wx
import wx.grid


class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "Manager")
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        overall = wx.grid.Grid(self)
        overall.CreateGrid(5,2)
        sizer.Add(overall, 0, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Fit()

app = wx.App(False)
MainFrame().Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

**EDIT (7/16/12):** Here's another example that better matches your description:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class ChartPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

########################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        chart = ChartPanel(self)
        chart.SetBackgroundColour("blue")

        # create some sizers
        mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        topSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        # change to VERTICAL if the buttons need to be stacked
        btnSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        for i in range(3):
            btn = wx.Button(self, label="Button #%s" % (i+1))
            btnSizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        # put the buttons next to the Panel on the top
        topSizer.Add(btnSizer, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        topSizer.Add(chart, 1, wx.EXPAND)

        mainSizer.Add(topSizer, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        mainSizer.AddSpacer(150,150)
        self.SetSizer(mainSizer)

########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="BoxSizer Example")
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I **need** multiple widgets!! I just remove them in this example!

Comment: I *must* use GridBagSizer, okay?

Comment: Actually you don't need it. You can use nested BoxSizers. I do it all the time. I'm not exactly sure what you expect anyway. With no other widgets, you're not going to see a difference. You need other widgets in the grid to see how your settings affect the layout.

Comment: I need to put 2 grids, 4 buttons is my final program.

Comment: First Grid is on the left and on the top, Three buttons are under the first grid. Second grid is on the right and on the top. There is a panel under the second grid, for a chart.

Comment: Do you think a BoxSizer can really do these?

Comment: I know so. I added another example where I tried to create something based on your description. It should give you an idea anyway.